# WIX set session property on custom action and access it

Tags: c#, .net, wix

i have a custum action where i call a dll which is being installed in the program files folder. Inside the custom action i am preparing a text which should be displayed to the person whom is installing my program at the end of the installation. 
Execution of the custom Action works fine, even assigning the value to the session in the custom action can be done without an exception

```
session["SEIA"] = "of the installation";
MessageBox.Show(session["SEIA"]);
```

the messagebox is displaying the right text. 
Now in the .wxs is done the following:

```
<Property Id="SEIA" Value="test 1234"/>
<Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALTEXT" Value="this is the value at the end"/>
<CustomAction Id="custactionID" BinaryKey="cust_actions" DllEntry="custActionMeth" Execute="immediate" Return='check'/>
<CustomAction Id="CA_Set_WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALTEXT" Property="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALTEXT" Value="this is the value at the end [SEIA]" Return='check'/>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="custactionID" After="InstallFinalize" />
  <Custom Action="CA_Set_WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALTEXT" After="custactionID">NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

now at the end of the installation should be an optional text which is:

> this is the value at the end of the installation

but the only thing displayed is:

> this is the value at the end test 1234

Some additional information:
Custom Action="custactionID" After="InstallFinalize" is needed as it is because i only now have access to the dll files in the installation folder.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you run your install with msi logging? msiexec /i yourinstaller.msi /l*v msilog.txt and then look in the log for the value of SEIA? My guess is you'll have one entry for SEIA where you have (s) on the line and it will be the right value and then you'll have SEIA with (c) on the line with the default value.

Comment: Yes that is exactly the case. so what can i do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i figured out a solution for the behavior of WIX. 
The main problem was that Information that is passed to the GUI is made in the client part. Stuff like copying the dll's to their destination is made in the server part. So it is impossible to have communication between the two parts. So how could i access the dll's in the client part. to get my stuff done was the question. This is very simple. I extract all the dll's to a temporary folder,

```
 string tempFold = @"C:\Windows\Temp\Extract";
        deleteDissTemp();
        Directory.CreateDirectory(tempFold);
        string parameters = string.Empty;
        parameters = string.Format(@"/a {0} /qn TARGETDIR=""{1}"" REINSTALLMODE=a", Path.Combine(path2Source, "DiSetup.msi"),
            tempFold);
        Process process = Process.Start("msiexec", parameters);
        process.WaitForExit();
```

then i take the dll's which are needed use them(by executing a dll), get the information for the gui and store it in the session.
I did not face any problems extracting the dll's from the msi package in use. Then i start the server part, copy my dlls to the defined place and finally i delete teh folder in the temp folder. The reason why deleting the temp folder is that the executed dll's were still in use and could not be delteted.(couldn't figure out how appdomain works :-(). Thanks anyway!!!